# Using gstreamer with videomixer & 2 cameras streaming over UDP

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, h.264, rtp, v4l2

I have a Raspberry Pi Compute module with 2 cameras. I'm trying to use gstreamer with v4l2src selecting /dev/video0 & /dev/video1 to continually run at about 20FPS and use videomixer to combine the images side-by-side then output H264 over RTP to a UDP port (read by another host)/

The default (current) RPi v4l2src driver does not support two cameras, but as of today a beta is available that does, however it requires the beta 4.4.6 kernel.

The problem I'm having is in getting the mixer connected.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#
# Script to start RPi Compute Module streaming over RTP (RFC3984)
# from both cameras
#
FPS=20                          # Frames per second
WIDTH=640                       # Image width
HEIGHT=480                      # Image height
UPLINK_HOST=192.168.1.73        # Receiving host
PORT=5200                       # UDP port
#
# TESTING WITH ONE CAMERA ONLY FOR THE MOMENT
#
function start_streaming
{
  gst-launch-1.0 -ve videomixer name=mixer  \
  ! x264enc \
  ! h264parse \
  ! rtph264pay config-interval=10 pt=96 \
  ! udpsink host=$UPLINK_HOST port=$PORT \
  v4l2src device=/dev/video0 \
  ! video/x-raw,format=AYUV,width=$WIDTH,height=$HEIGHT,framerate=$FPS/1 \
  ! mixer.
}

# Start streaming on both cameras simultaneously
echo Image size: $WIDTH x $HEIGHT
echo Frame rate: $FPS
echo Starting cameras 0 and 1 streaming to $UPLINK_HOST:$PORT
start_streaming

# Wait until everything has finished
wait

exit 0
# end
```

What I'm getting is the rather useless message:

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link v4l2src0 to mixer
```

I've fiddled about rather a lot and got nowhere - it's probably something trivial, but be blowed if I can see it !

Many thanks

Nick

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the chosen format. You use the AYUV while your camera does not support it. Try to replace the AYUV by I420.